# How to show namespace-use errors?

Tags: php

Is there any way to get any sort of error, be it exceptions, error codes or logging, for when the aliasee introduced by `use` does not exist?

For example, I tried this one (i.e. using all error signalling I know of):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use \Foobar as Frob; // \Foobar is actually unknown
print("still here\n");
```

Together with this line of command in Bash:

`display_errors=on php love.php`

and get:

```
still here
```

as the sole output. I looked into `php_errors.log`, but nothing is there.

PHP designers, in their much valued sanity, surely have thought of something?

I understand `use` is just an alias for *alias* in the world of PHP, yet I don't see why there should not be errors for fully qualified referees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` statements as such don't really *do* anything much. All they do is alias a namespaced name to another name of your choice, henceforth allowing you to refer to that shortened alias instead of the full name. That's it. Nothing more happens. The class/function/file isn't actually being loaded at this point nor any other sort of validation is being done. This is because there are many ways to load the actual class that alias refers to, and you may want to do this after the fact later on. Most likely using an autoloader, which will attempt to load the class when it's first actually used.

So: no, there's no way besides trying to *use* the class.

```
$frob = new Frob; // Fatal error: class Foobar not found
```

Comment: +1 for the code sample. But it reads like your intro paragraph makes for a reason for not having errors for fully qualified referees, but it's not really.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. The philosophy in PHP, especially using autoloaders, is to delay loading of files as much as possible. Even if you are `use`ing a class at the top of the file, you may never actually instantiate it during execution. So it'd be a needless performance hit to actually load and validate the file, merely because you mentioned it in a `use` alias. That's a byproduct of the PHP execution model. The error can only surface during actual runtime when the class is actually used.

Comment: I see. It would be nice if they gave that rationale in their use-documentation. And imho it would have been saner to name that thing _alias_.

Comment: Well, `use Foo\Bar` is just shorthand for `use Foo\Bar as Bar`. With the `as` is becomes somewhat more obvious that it's an alias. Also, `use` and `as` already exist as parser tokens (`function () use ()`, `foreach (.. as ..)`), so I'm sure not wanting to introduce additional keywords is part of the rationale.

Comment: Not more obvious if you come from languages with more complex namespace support, like C++ or Python ;) It almost looks like `as` is to alias an alias.

Comment: Yeah, PHP namespaces have nothing to do with Python-style modules and imports. It's literally just an addition to the naming system, it does absolutely nothing for loading, importing, scoping or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not report any error because there is no error in your code.

The `use` declaration says that `Frob` is just another name for `\Foobar`. It is just a declaration, `PHP` does not try to load `\Foobar` or check if it exists at that point.

As long as you don't use either `Frob` or `\Foobar` in the code, that `use` declaration has no effect.

But if you try to use it:

```
$frob = new Frob();
```

and `\Foobar` is not a class then be sure `PHP` will trigger a fatal error and stop the execution of the script.

The `use` declaration works like the symbolic links in the file system. You can create the file `a` that is a symbolic link to `b` and as long as you don't try to read from `a` (or `b`), nobody cares if `b` exists or not.